# Inequality condition for induced norms of iterative matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, matrix-norms

Assume that $x^{(k+1)} = Bx^{(k)} + c$ and $||B||<1$ for some induced matrix norm and $x^{(0)} = x_0$. I need to prove:

$||x^{(k)} - x^*|| \geq \frac {||B^{k}||}{(I-||B||)}||x^{(1)}-x_0||$

However, I'm getting stuck at proving the following:

$||(I-B)^{-1}|| \leq \frac{1}{1-||B||}$

Currently all I know is

$\frac {1}{||I-B||} \leq ||(I-B)^{-1}||$

But I don't know if this is of any help.

And,
$\frac {1}{1-||B||}>1$ because $||B||<1$

Please let me know how to proceed from here. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Which one ? The one I'm getting stuck on or the main inequality ?

Comment: Very sorry, I didn't read your answer correctly. See my answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof of the inequality $\|(I-B)^{-1}\| \leq \frac 1 {1-\|B\|}$: we have $(I-B)^{-1}=I+B+B^{2}+...$ so $\|(I-B)^{-1}\| \leq 1+\|B\|+\|B||^{2}+...=\frac 1 {1-\|B\|}$. These steps are valid since $\|B\| <1$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the expansion $||(I-B)^{-1}|| \leq 1 + ||B|| + ||B||^2 ... = \frac{1}{1-||B||}$ ? How did you arrive at this inequality ?

Comment: Actually no, the equation was correct earlier

Comment: The series $\sum (B^{n})_{ij}$ converges for each $i,j$ (because $|a_{ij}| \leq \|A\|$). Thus we can define a matrix $M$ by $M_{ij} =\sum (B^{n})_{ij}$. Now we can verify that $M(I-B)=I-B)M=I$ so $M=(I-B)^{-1}$. Once you have this you only need the fact that $\|B^{n}\| \leq \|B\|^{n}$.

Comment: Just understood the solution. Thank you so much for the help @KaviRamaMurthy !